# What does the asterisk before variable signify?

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone know where I can find documentation about what the asterisk before variables is used for.  I don't understand it and it's starting to become a problem because I have noticed you don't need it for all types for e.g. BOOL doesn't return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's C notation for a pointer.

You don't need it for a BOOL because it is not an object and so it isn't passed by reference

Have a look at the [Introduction to Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163) part of the documentation.